# Angular2 - How to change the size of DevExtreme load indicator in datagrid control

Tags: angular, devextreme, dx-data-grid

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/

Above is the API reference provided by the Devextreme team. I have used the **loadPanel** property to change the spinner indicator to point to a custom gif.
Here is the property exposed by the Devextreme team

```
loadPanel: {
    enabled: "auto",
    height: 90,
    indicatorSrc: "",
    showIndicator: true,
    showPane: true,
    text: "Loading...",
    width: 200
}
```

which I have changed to something like,

```
loadPanel: {
    enabled: "auto",
    height: 90,
    indicatorSrc: "images/MyCustom.gif",
    showIndicator: true,
    showPane: false,
    text: "Loading...",
    width: 200
}
```

However, the GIF appears shrunk and the **height** and **width** properties are only for the size of the box pane around it. Tried to change the size by setting a CSS style for the indicator class but didn't work

```
/deep/ .dx-loadindicator-content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Could anyone achieve this?

Comment: Where did you write this css rule?

Comment: In the component's CSS

Comment: Link doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loadPanel.width` and `loadPanel.height` options are directly connected with load panel geometry. And they don't affect an icon size. But you can customize icon size via CSS as you pointed in the question. Just use the following css selector:

```
/deep/ .dx-datagrid .dx-loadindicator {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you much. Guess I am bad with CSS. :)